# Splitting a number off prefix of a string on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Say I have a string like "123alpha".  I can use NSNumber to get the 123 out, but how can I determine the part of the string that NSNumber didn't use?

Comment: Did you wish to vote to close [this question that you recently commented on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68598450/)? If you know of a Python duplicate, that could work. Deleting this comment in a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSScanner` to both get the value and the rest of the string.

```
NSString *input = @"123alpha";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:input];
float number;
[scanner scanFloat:&number];
NSString *rest = [input substringFromIndex:[scanner scanLocation]];
```

If it is important to know exactly what is left after parsing the value this is a better approach than trying to trim characters. While I can't think of any particular bad input at the moment that would fail the solution suggested by the OP in the comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389804/splitting-a-number-off-prefix-of-a-string-on-iphone/4389993#4389993), it looks like a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

if your numbers are always at the beginning or end of a string and you want only the remaining characters, you could trim with a character set.

```
NSString *alpha = @"123alpha";
NSString *stripped = [alpha stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"]];
```

Comment: Hmmm.  The numbers can be negative decimals.  But if I 1) trim leading -ve signs, then 2) trim digits, then 3) trim a single period (if there), and finally 4) trim digits,  I think I'll have what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: @Scott: Why not just include those characters in the character set?

Answer (score 0):

If its starts out as a `char *` (as opposed to an `NSString *`), you can use `strtol()` to get the number and discover where the number ends in a single call.

Comment: It is a NSString, but could be converted, except that I think it is in Unicode.

Comment: Then you could use the `UTF8String` method, but it might be better to go for one of the answers that uses `NSString` directly.