# How to extract out a non-continuous matrix from a larger matrix based on a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

(this is in python 2.7.13)

If I have matrix A:

```
a =[
  [0,1,0,0,0,1],  
  [4,1,0,3,2,0],  
  [0,0,1,0,0,0],  
  [0,1,0,0,1,0],  
  [0,0,0,0,1,0],  
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  
]
```

and a list of index's `b =[0, 1, 3]`

I would like to extract a smaller matrix from the `matrix a` using the index `list b` as the rows and columns.

So, it would be:

```
[0] row of matrix a; columns[0,1,3]
[1] row of matrix a; columns[0,1,3]
[3] row of matrix a; columns[0,1,3]
```

Which would equal, as example:

```
[
  [0,1,0], #0 row, 0,1,3 items
  [4,1,3], #1 row, 0,1,3 items
  [0,1,0]  #3 row, 0,1,3 items
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by:

```
a =[
  [0,1,0,0,0,1],  
  [4,1,0,3,2,0],  
  [0,0,1,0,0,0],  
  [0,1,0,0,1,0],  
  [0,0,0,0,1,0],  
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  
]
 
b = [0, 1, 3]
c = [[a[i][j] for j in b] for i in b]
print(c)
# ===>
# [[0, 1, 0], [4, 1, 3], [0, 1, 0]]
```

(Anyway, Python2 is no longer supported: [link](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). I recommend you use Python3+NumPy, which supports various matrix operations such as flexible indexing that you want.)